AWS CDK create S3 event notification to SQS message in Localstack
I'm working to create a simple way to use AWS CDK to create a bucket and an SQS queue where any object created in the bucket will create a message in the SQS Queue. I have been able to make it work with the AWS CLI, but not with the CDK.
I've tried the following code:
    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------
     * SQS Queue
     * --------------------------------------------------
     */

    const queue = new sqs.Queue(this, queueName, {
      encryption: sqs.QueueEncryption.UNENCRYPTED,
    });

    queue.grantSendMessages(new iam.ServicePrincipal('s3.amazonaws.com'));

    /**
     * --------------------------------------------------
     * S3 Bucket
     * --------------------------------------------------
     */

    const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, bucketName, {});

    bucket.addEventNotification(
      s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED,
      new s3n.SqsDestination(queue)
    );

    const bucketPolicy = new iam.PolicyStatement({
      actions: ['sqs:SendMessage'],
      effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
      principals: [new iam.ServicePrincipal('s3.amazonaws.com')],
      resources: [queue.queueArn],
      conditions: {
        ArnLike: {
          'aws:SourceArn': bucket.bucketArn,
        },
      },
    });

    queue.addToResourcePolicy(bucketPolicy);


This is creating the bucket and queue (in Localstack), however running aws s3 cp ./some_file.txt s3://bucket_name/some_file.txt doesn't create a message in the SQS queue.

Can you try using s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED_PUT instead of s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED to see if it does make any difference?

Still not working with OBJECT_CREATED_PUT

This appears to be an issue with Localstack (when not using Pro), so I wrapped a fix with a condition check to see if I'm in the LS env:
    const bucket = new s3.Bucket(this, bucketName, {
      bucketName,
    });

    bucket.addEventNotification(
      s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED,
      new s3n.SqsDestination(queue)
    );

    if (process.env.IS_LOCALSTACK) {
      const cfnBucket = bucket.node.defaultChild as s3.CfnBucket;
      cfnBucket.notificationConfiguration = {
        queueConfigurations: [
          {
            event: s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED,
            queue: queue.queueArn,
          },
        ],
      };
    }

